# datagrid crushes ExpressionBlend 4

Tags: datagrid, crash, expression-blend

If I try to add a DataGrid, the Blend 4 crashes.

If I open a project, that has Datagrid (that was added in VS2010), the Blend can't open it in the designer, but give an error:

The name DataGrid does not exist in the namespace "http//schemas.microsoft.com/winfx//xaml/presentation/sdk

Interestingly everything worked well before, and I can't imagine what happened.

The error emerged after Windows update, but persists despite that I reverted to the previous installation state. I reinstalled the Blend4 with sp1, but nothing changed.

Does anybody else experienced similar issue?

Thanks in advance

Gabor

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

I unblocked the silverlight_sdk.exe file (in propeties), and then reinstalled.

Interestingly only schema mappings didn't work.

If I changed the

xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"

declaration to concrete namespace and assembly:

xmlns:sdk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"

(as was in SL3), the DataGrid showed up in the designer as before, but in that case I have to add all other assemblies in the sdk manually.

Gabor